# Use kint from within twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I don't like debugging php code, it is slow and takes a restart and whatnot.

So i typically use [kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/) to output objects that I don't understand, and to get to know them what is on there.

Well, thanks to twigs policies, I cannot call kint's `Kint::dump()` function any longer.

I could use `{{dump()}}` but dump is really really ugly and a thing of the past.

what are my options?

Comment: Well, may be you want to give a try [Symfony VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Symfony full-stack framework (what I assume, as you tagged it with [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2)), you can use `{{ dump() }}` as of Symfony 2.7 to get a very nice output (and `{% dump() %}` to get it in the toolbar instead of breaking the page layout).

If you don't use the symfony full-stack framework, you can install the `VarDumper` component as a standalone component and install `symfony/twig-bridge` and register the `DumpExtension` to have the better dump function.

If you still want to use Kind, install the kind library and write a custom [Twig extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) ([docs when using Symfony full-stack](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Responding to a really old question, but I figured it would be pretty easy to write a kint extension to do just that: kinting from twig templates.

**services.yml**

```
services:
  dev.kint_extension:
    class: "AppBundle\\Twig\\KintExtension"
    public: true
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

**KintExtension.php**

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Twig/KintExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class KintExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  public function getFunctions(){
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('kint', array($this, "kint")),
    ];
  }

  public function getName(){
    return "kint_extension";
  }

  public function kint($var){
    \Kint::dump($var);
  }
}
```

Now you can easily kint() from anywhere in twig.

```
{{ kint(any_variable) }}
```